# Group by on a different table

Tags: php, mysql

Consider these two tables:

```
# table: feeding
feeding_id          int(15)
user_id             int(15)
herd_id             int(15)
feeding_datetime    datetime
herd_num_animals    smallint(5)

# table feeding_supp
feeding_id          int(15)
supp_name           varchar(50)
supp_weight         double(8,2)
supp_dry_weight     double(5,2)
supp_price          double(9,2)
```

I want to know how many kg is fed per week. By using `SUM(fs.supp_weight)` and group the results per year/ per week, I get the total of weight. That works fine.

However, I want to have the weight that is fed **per animal**. So my thought was to use `SUM(fs.supp_weight) / SUM(f.herd_num_animals)`. But since the group by is on another table, the `SUM(f.herd_num_animals)` results in a the sum of the whole table, instead of per year/ week.

How can I accomplish that?

For info, this is the whole query:

```sql
SELECT
    f.herd_id,
    f.herd_num_animals,
    h.herd_name,
    YEAR(f.feeding_datetime) AS year,
    WEEK(f.feeding_datetime,3) AS week,
    SUM(fs.supp_weight) / SUM( f.herd_num_animals ) AS supp_weight
FROM 
    feeding_supp fs
LEFT JOIN 
    feeding f ON f.feeding_id = fs.feeding_id
LEFT JOIN 
    herd h ON h.herd_id = f.herd_id
WHERE 
    f.herd_id=?
GROUP BY 
    WEEK(feeding_datetime,3)
ORDER BY 
    f.herd_id ASC, 
    YEAR(f.feeding_datetime) ASC, 
    WEEK(f.feeding_datetime,3) ASC
```

Comment: `GROUP BY h.herd_name,YEAR(f.feeding_datetime) ,
    WEEK(f.feeding_datetime,3)` OR herd_num_animals insted of  herd_name is that consititues an animal

Comment: #sqlfiddle will help....

Comment: Note that money is normally DECIMAL. I suspect that the other DOUBLE data types should be DECIMAL too.